# How do I determine whether value in array is in its correct sorted position?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, if-statement, selection-sort

I have a selection-sort algorithm that sorts 47 different vertical red bars into an order, lowest to highest. During the sorting, I want the bars that are placed in the correct position to turn blue. The way I want to do this is by making an if-statement in my drawBar method. I need to determine if a bar is smallest and at index 0, and if it is, then change the color to blue using Expo. Then if the second smallest bar is at index 1 it can turn blue, if the third smallest at index 2 it can turn blue, and so on. This can be done using a for loop. But I have tried to implement this in many different ways in my drawBar method, but nothing turns blue. All the bars remain red and I have no error messages. How do I fix this if statement to get what I want stated above? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Lab15st extends Applet
{

    private int numBars;        // number of bars to be sorted
    private int barHeight[];    // array of bar heights
    private int sortDelay;      // delay between comparison iteration

    public void init()
    {
        numBars = 47;
        sortDelay = 50;
        barHeight = new int[numBars];
        getBarValues();
    }
    public void getBarValues()
    {
        Random rand = new Random(3333);
        for (int k = 0; k < numBars; k++)
            barHeight[k] = rand.nextInt(591) + 10;  // range of 10..600
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        showFrame(g);
        displayBars(g);
        sortBars(g);
    }
    public void showFrame(Graphics g)
    {
        Expo.setBackground(g,Expo.black);
        Expo.setColor(g,Expo.white);
        Expo.fillRectangle(g,20,20,980,630);
    }
    public void drawBar(Graphics g, int k)
    {
        for (int p = 0; p < numBars; p++)
        {
        int smallest = findSmallestItemIndex(p);
        int y2 = 630;
        int x1 = 35 + k * 20;
        int y1 = y2 - barHeight[k];
        int x2 = x1 + 10;
        if(barHeight[i] == smallest && barHeight[i] == barHeight[p])
        Expo.setColor(g,Expo.blue);
        else
        Expo.setColor(g,Expo.red);
        Expo.fillRectangle(g,x1,y1,x2,y2);
        }
    }
    public void eraseBar(Graphics g, int k) // not used in 80 point version
    {
        int y2 = 630;
        int x1 = 35 + k * 20;
        int y1 = y2 - barHeight[k];
        int x2 = x1 + 10;
        Expo.setColor(g,Expo.white);
        Expo.fillRectangle(g,x1,y1,x2,y2);
    }

    public void displayBars(Graphics g)
    {  
      Expo.setColor(g,Expo.red);
        for (int k = 0; k < numBars; k++)
            drawBar(g,k);
    }

    public void swap(Graphics g, int m, int n) 
    {                                          
     Expo.delay(sortDelay);
     
     eraseBar(g,m);
     eraseBar(g,n);
     
     int temp = barHeight[m];
     barHeight[m] = barHeight[n];
     barHeight[n] = temp;
     
     drawBar(g,m);
     drawBar(g,n);
   }
    public void sortBars(Graphics g)        
    {                                       
     for (int p = 0; p < numBars; p++)
      {
       int smallest = findSmallestItemIndex(p);
       if (barHeight[p] != barHeight[smallest])
         swap(g,p,smallest);
      }
   }
   public int getItem(int index) { 
     return barHeight[index]; 
    }
   public int findSmallestItemIndex(int start)
   {
     int smallest = start;
     for (int k = start+1; k < numBars; k++)
     if (barHeight[k] < barHeight[smallest])
       smallest = k;
     return smallest;
   }
}
```

Comment: I would make a copy of the array you are sorting, sort it with Collections.sort, and then check whether a location in your partially sorted array has the same height as the same location in your pre-sorted array.

Comment: You should not be using `Applet` or even `JApplet` as they are outdated and no longer supported.  You should be using a `JFrame` with a `JPanel` and overriding `paintComponent` to do your painting.  Please check out [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) in the Java Tutorials.